# What is the purpose of having private variable with corresponding setter method?

Tags: java, oop

When we have a setter method for private variable in java, what is the purpose of making the variable private?

We are having private variables to restrict the user not to access the state of an instance directly. But in sometimes, we are having corresponding setter and getter methods to access and change the state of the private variable. If so, then why do we make the variable private? We can just have public variable instead right?

Comment: It also makes it alot easier to identify all the places where the variable is modified.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rationale is that you're *hiding* the implementation. When you call

```
setX(23);
```

your corresponding variable `x` is hidden from client classes and can't be directly observed or modified.

Why is this good ?

1. it hides the implementation. You can change `x` at a later date to (say) a `string`, a `double` etc. and your client code doesn't have to change. `x` could even disappear and calling `setX()` would actually perform some different *but equivalent* function.
2. by implementing a setter function, you can enforce validation etc. Otherwise you can't prevent someone setting `x` to an invalid (e.g. negative) value.
3. (this is a Java-specific benefit rather than a general OO benefit). Lots of Java frameworks work with objects using the *JavaBeans* convention. i.e. for a property `x` there will exist a corresponding `getX()`/`setX()` (or `isX()` if it's a `boolean`). By adhering to convention your class will interoperate nicely with these frameworks.

Note there are arguments for not having setters but rather implementing *immutable* objects (so you'd set your value via the constructor alone). That makes the object thread-safe and debugging/reasoning about the object state easier.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a question of having a setter or not, it's a matter of **encapsulation**: member variables should almost always be private in order to hide the implementation.

Here's a good example I've recently seen: someone was asking why Java doesn't have an `AtomicFloat` type and someone else pointed out that you can actually implement it using `AtomicInteger` and doing bit tricks to convert back and forth between `int` and `float`. Now the class looked something like:

```
class AtomicFloat {
     private AtomicInteger value;

     public float get() {
         // turn value into float
     }

     public void set(float newValue) {
         // turn newValue into int
     }

     // CAS and whatever else
}
```

Now to the outside it seems I have all I need: I can use this class as an `AtomicFloat` and I don't care about what's going on inside. Now imagine if the user could peek in and see that all my methods are actually doing stage magic with an `AtomicInteger`. That would really mess things up!

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the caller from doing something stupid. Imagine a Date class (a simple one, not Java's nor Jodatime's Date class) and it stores the day of the month, the month itself and the year itself in int fields:

```
public int dayOfMonth;
public int monthOfYear;
public int year;
```

With that, there's nothing to stop a caller from creating an instance of this Date class for the 234th day of the 56th month of a year.

If on the other hand you use setter methods for private fields, those setter methods can check that the values being passed through are sensible (eg that `setMonth()` isn't called with a value outside the range 1 to 12 etc)

Answer (score 0):

`setter` is mutator method & a mutator method is a method used to `control changes to a variable`.
but `private` modifier `controls the accessiability of a variable` from other class
a parameter may be made `write-only` simply by defining an setter but not by private modifier

Answer (score 0):

This methodology is often used when for example:

```
Class Car {
    Private int wheels
    Private int tyres
    Private time lastUpdated

    - setWheels(int i) {
        lastUpdated = Time.Now
        wheels = i
        tyres = i
    }

    - setTyres(int i) {
        lastUpdated = Time.Now
        tyres = i
        wheels = i
    }
}
```

Say when that variable gets updated you want to also do some other stuff that depends on it.

This is a simple example, so the number of wheels is directly related to the number of tyres, so we can set that when you use setter methods and we also want to know when the car was last updated, basically it allows you to perform other tasks dependant upon the variable changing.

The reason you make the variable private is so that you have to use the setter methods when accessing the variable from outside the class.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Will